# How to mock the custom TypeScript function result in Cypress?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I've created a new Vite TypeScript project on my local environment.

```
import './style.css'
import { add } from './calculator'

document.querySelector<HTMLSpanElement>('#app')!.innerHTML = add(2, 3).toString()
```

I've also added a new TypeScript file called `calculator` that has a single method `add`

```
export function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b
}
```

I've got a Cypress (10.11.0) installed and have this basic test:

```
import * as calculator from "../../src/calculator";

describe('empty spec', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:5173/', {
      onBeforeLoad() {
        cy.stub(calculator, 'add').returns(10)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Result: the page displays `5`.
Question: how to make it display `10` instead (as specified in the test)?

I have tried placing the stub in places other than `onBeforeLoad`. I've managed to mock the dom function return types like `document.getElementById` functions; but I can't achieve the same result with my custom scripts.

I've also purchased the Cypress testing course in Udemy but it didn't cover this particular scenario.

Moreover I went through the Youtube videos and even found one that offered a plugin that supposed to solve my problem but it is a JavaScript one, not the TypeScript and it didn't work for me either.

Finally I spoke to my colleague at work and he couldn't find the solution either and suggested me just to give up.

Answer (score 0):

The stub is ok, the problem is you are importing another instance of `calculator` into the test. It has no connection to the instance running in the app (apart from it's created from the same code).

You want to get the same instance this way

```js
import calculator from './calculator'
const { add } = calculator;

if (window.Cypress) {
  window.calculator = calculator
}
```

**test**

```js
describe('empty spec', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:5173/', {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        cy.stub(win.calculator, 'add').returns(10)
      }
    })
  })
})
```